# app relaunch before test start detox

Tags: react-native, detox

React Native app relaunches before running the Detox e2e test suite. Initially it displays the first screen of the application and relaunches the application test suite.

The problem with this behavior is that, when I am trying to run the test suite on com.bitbar.com device farming service portal, the test case runs successfully, while it has to fail and write the logs to a file.

I tested it locally, if we don't try to log the records to a log file then it successfully runs the app, but if we try to log the records to a log file, then the test case is getting stopped at the first (unnecessary) screen launch, making the test case PASS. how to stop this behavior of detox test case.

testcase:

```
describe('Example', () => {
it('Login Screen, Logging into the app', async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
     await element(by.id(TestIDs.LoginScreen.usernameInput)).typeText('+1234567890');
    await element(by.id(TestIDs.LoginScreen.passwordInput)).typeText('0123');
    await Expect(element(by.id('not found'))).toBeVisible();
    await Expect(element(by.id(TestIDs.LoginScreen.submitButton))).toBeVisible();
    // await element(by.id(TestIDs.LoginScreen.submitButton)).tap();
})
```

command to run test without saving the log to

```
detox test --configuration android.emu.debug -l verbose
```

command to run test and save the log to

```
"detox test --configuration android.emu.debug -l verbose  > detox.log 2>&1 "
```

The log

```
`
    send: {"type":"isReady","params":{},"messageId":-1000}
 INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.mobile.repletehealth.DetoxTest
 INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
 INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=AndroidJUnitRunner
 INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
 INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
 com.mobile.repletehealth.DetoxTest:
 INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=runDetoxTests
 INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
 nstrumentation stdout: 
 onMessage: {"messageId":-1000,"type":"ready","params":{}}
  rbx
 send: {"type":"reactNativeReload","params":{},"messageId":-1000}
 onMessage: {"messageId":-1000,"type":"ready","params":{}}
  rbx
 send: {"type":"invoke","params":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"com.wix.detox.espresso.EspressoDetox"},"method":"perform","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"android.support.test.espresso.Espresso"},"method":"onView","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"com.wix.detox.espresso.DetoxMatcher"},"method":"matcherForTestId","args":["usernameInput"]}}]}},{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions"},"method":"typeText","args":["+1234567890"]}}]},"messageId":1}
 onMessage: {"messageId":1,"type":"invokeResult","params":{"result":"(null)"}}
  rbx
 send: {"type":"invoke","params":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"com.wix.detox.espresso.EspressoDetox"},"method":"perform","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"android.support.test.espresso.Espresso"},"method":"onView","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"com.wix.detox.espresso.DetoxMatcher"},"method":"matcherForTestId","args":["passwordInput"]}}]}},{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions"},"method":"typeText","args":["0123"]}}]},"messageId":2}
 onMessage: {"messageId":2,"type":"invokeResult","params":{"result":"(null)"}}
  rbx
 send: {"type":"cleanup","params":{"stopRunner":true},"messageId":3}
 onMessage: {"messageId":3,"type":"cleanupDone","params":{}}`
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever solve this?